# Entity Framework configuration to set default value to the first foreign Id available

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

Using EF Core, I'm adding a migration for a new column which is a foreign key to another table, which lets say contains id's 1,2,3 right now. I need to keep the data in my table so, to make this legal, I have to set a value manually as I do it:

```
public partial class AddMyTableNewProperty1 : DbMigration
{
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "MyOtherEntityId", c => c.Int());

    // I ADD THIS IN MANUALLY:
    Sql(@"UPDATE dbo.MyEntity SET MyOtherEntityId = 1 where MyOtherEntity IS NULL");
}
public override void Down()
{
    DropColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "MyOtherEntityId");
}
}
```

1. I do not like to update migration code manually.
2. I would like to keep consistent with my project and have this in the entity configurations section.

In My Entity Configuration, I'd like something like:

```
modelBuilder.Property(m => m.MyOtherEntityId).HasDefaultValue(1);
```

But without specifying "1" - just the first item available is needed. "1" may not exist.

Comment: Okay, and what is your question?

Comment: Do I really have to edit the question to add "How do I achieve this?"

Comment: Typically when adding a foreign key like this you'd either have a specific default in mind or leave it null to indicate that it's unknown.  There's no way to define a table column to get a value from another table like this without doing a manual update like you already have (which could be changed to pull a value from the other table)

Comment: @egmfrs no, because you added it in the comments

Comment: @juharr thank you for confirming this - yes I was thinking SET fkID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM table)

Comment: @egmfrs Yes, you do.  Don't be rude about it.

Comment: @Amy are you down-voting my post and holding me to ransom until I update it?

Comment: You were rude to me.  Think of it as encouragement for editing your question.  Don't want a downvote?  Don't be rude.

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here for everyone to read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/

Comment: Apparently the tool/library/framework you are using lacks the functionality you are asking. Hence your question is a feature request and should be posted to their issue tracker. I really don't understand what are you expecting here.

Comment: @IvanStoev I was not aware that it lacked the functionality. My expectation was for advice or an approach that could I could use to achieve the goal I outlined.

Comment: @egmfrs Fair enough. Unfortunately they (EF Core devs) left this (and many other cases) for us (devs using it). Modifying the generated migration code and `Sql` method is all you got. May be some day in vNext ...